# Split CAD (step .stp) file into separate parts which can then be imported to Unity and moved relative to each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, solidworks

I need to use Unity to simulate a camera moving through a complex object, I have a CAD (.stp) file of the complex object already.

I can convert this assembly to .obj, and then import the .obj into Unity. However this loses the hierarchical information such as different parts. I need certain components to be separate game objects in Unity, so I can move the components relative to each other and highlight them to the camera. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: **How** do you convert to OBJ? Unity allows to create individual objects for each mesh group in the OBJ -> then you can individually move them

Comment: I think this explains what I need to do - split the object into two different mesh groups within the obj, the question is then how to do that? I used Solidworks to convert the .stp into a .obj

Comment: I don't know how your converter works or what it supports but this doesn't look like a coding related issue then ... I can tell you if such mesh groups exist if I see the OBJ .. that's all ^^ From there you could use [Runtime OBJ Importer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/runtime-obj-importer-49547) which provides the option to split objects on the groups into different GameObjects ... Be aware though that in OBJ there isn't really something like a hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

[Probuilder ProBuilderize](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.3/manual/Object_ProBuilderize.html) lets you select determined faces of a game object and then with [Detach Faces](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.probuilder@4.3/manual/Face_Detach.html) split it into a spare gameobject.

You would need to download the probuilder package with the [package manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html), then display the probuilder window (Tools > ProBuilder > ProBuilder Window), select the faces of the spare part you wnat to set apart (all the faces) and click on "Detach Faces".

Comment: This sounds really promising - thanks a lot - I will give it a go and get back to you

Comment: I was amazed that there was a chance to do that inside unity itself. Its is an awesome feature. If the gameobject is very detailed and there are a lot of faces to detach, it might take a while to select them all and mus be done carefully but it is so awesome to have the chance to obtain spare sub-gameObjects.